# actix-web error accepting connection: Too many open files (os error 24)

Tags: linux, rust, actix-web

I am using actix-web for an HTTP server, it usually has about 200 requests per 12 seconds, After the first few requests I am continuously getting this error
`[2023-07-23T07:39:48Z ERROR actix_server::accept] error accepting connection: Too many open files (os error 24)`

I tried increasing the connection using `ulimit` and also tried changing the `max_connection` configurations of Actix. But this did not help either.

i am using actix version `actix-web = "4.3.1"` and the current `ulimit -n` value is `1000`. and running on a server with spec

Answer (score 1):

Could there be some other process with many open file handles?

Here are a few tips that might point you to what is causing the problem.

To list all open file descriptors:

```
ls -l /proc/$$/fd
```

You might want to try setting a larger (than 1,000) limit and see if that helps:

```
ulimit -n 15000
```

You could use the [ss](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ss.8.html) command to gain more insight into what's happening on your system (socket statistics). For example, with this command:

```
ss -s
```